# Sorting std::list of pointers

Tags: visual-c++

How do I sort a `std::list<someClass*>`? The workaround posted here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/265109 doesn’t seem to work.

> error: '`greater<class Object *>`' has already been instantiated from the primary template

I’m using MS VC++ 6.0 as IDE.

Comment: That's a really old bug, which Microsoft compiler are you actually using?

Answer (score 1):

Probably this might help you: [STL Algorithms: sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/)